# How to read .properties file running with plugged eclipse tomcat server outside project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, properties

I've the need to have some configuration file outside the WAR structure so I can update my service keeping the conf files unaffected.
Searching around seems that the best solution is to use `classLoader.getResourceAsStream()` and set the conf file container folder in the `shared.loader` property of `catalina.properties`.
Doing so the folder enter in the classpath.

I've made a test on a standalone tomcat server and everything works, but I'm not able to make it work in Eclipse IDE with the plugged server.
I've edited the `catalina.properties` under Servers folder of Eclipse and added the conf folder under the installation directory of the plugged server.
I ask the experts what am I doing wrong.

Sorry but I'm not able to read the .properties file as suggested.
This is my try:

```
   ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("prop_folder/jpa.properties"));        

        String propValue = properties.getProperty("test");  

        System.out.println("Property value is: " + propValue);
```

Seems that getResourceAsStream() didn't find any resource.

The prop_folder is under the root of the Eclipse plugged server

Comment: Suggestion : use the application context file to declare a property that points to the configuration file, for instance :  `<Environment name="conf/myconf" value="/home/myapp/myconf.properties" type="java.lang.String" >` . Get the property value via JNDI interface. Then use the value of the property to load your file via the `getRessourceAsStream()`. Should work outside the box as it does not require to modify any tomcat level files. So you can run your webpp in any servlet container (tomcat, jetty ... )

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... one question:the path value can be any folder under  $CATALINA_HOME? I don't want to lose the config folder while updating via WAR

Comment: With this way the path can be any path accessible by the user running the tomcat instance. Basically you can put your configuration file where you want, provided that the user running the tomcat has read privileges on the path.